# How to Unit Test Resilience4j circuit breaker fallback methods

Tags: junit, resilience4j

I am trying to Unit test the `Resilience4j` `CircuitBreaker` configuration for my service. But I am unable to call the fallback method when I throw `HttpServerErrorException`. However I try to `mock` the objects the call is not going to the fallback method.

The fallback works fine. When `AService` fails, the call is directed to fallback method calling `BService`. How do I write test cases to verify them?

I am new to Resilience4j and fallback patterns. Please help me to test this.

**Service class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @NonNull
    private AService aService;

    @NonNull
    private BService bService;



    @CircuitBreaker(name = "resilienceConfig", fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    @TimeLimiter(name = "resilienceConfig")
    @Override
    public Mono<List<PojoClass>> method(Mono<PojoClass2> pc) {

        return pc
            .map(PojoClass2::getPojoClass2)
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
            .map(Pojo3::getId)
            .flatMap(service -> aService.method(param1, param2))
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
            .map(this::changeValues)
            .collectList();


    }

    public Mono<List<PojoClass>> fallback(Mono<PojoClass2> pc, Throwable ex) {
        return pc
            .map(PojoClass2::getPojoClass2)
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
            .map(Pojo3::getId)
            .flatMap(service -> bService.method(param1, param2))
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
            .map(this::changeValues)
            .collectList();
    }
}
```

**ServiceTest**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private AService aService;

    @Mock
    private BService bService;

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Test
    public void enrichException() {

    doThrow(new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
            .when(aService)
            .method(param1, param2);
            
    Mono<List<PojoClass>> pojo = serviceImpl.method(param1);


    }
}
```

Comment: Your test is just wrong. You are trying to use mockito runner with Spring Boot test. Which do you want a mockito based test or a spring boot test. If it is the latter remove the runner and use the `SpringRunner` and use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` and autowire the service instead of creating it. .